# How to link in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

How can I link in javascript, I want to link suggestion.full to #

JS:

```
var domains = ['hotmail.com', 'gmail.com', 'aol.com'];
var topLevelDomains = ["com", "net", "org"];

$('#email').on('blur', function(event) {
    console.log("event ", event);
    console.log("this ", $(this));
    $(this).mailcheck({
        domains: domains, // optional
        topLevelDomains: topLevelDomains, // optional
        suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
            // callback code
            console.log("suggestion ", suggestion.full);
            $('#suggestion').html("Did you mean? <b><i>" + suggestion.full + "</b></i>?");
        },
        empty: function(element) {
            // callback code
            $('#suggestion').html('No Suggestions :(');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
                            <p id="suggestion"></p>
```

I tried:

```
$('#suggestion').html("Did you mean? <b><i>" + <a href="#">'suggestion.full</a>' + "</b></i>?");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: $('#suggestion').html("Did you mean? <b><i>" + suggestion.full + "</b></i>?"); this line is not working?

Comment: it works but I want to create a hyperlink of the function suggestion.full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some quote placement and type mixups. Try this instead:

```
$('#suggestion').html('Did you mean? <b><i><a href="#">'+suggestion.full+'</a></b></i>?');
```

If `suggestion.full` is the URL, you can add it into the href like this:

```
$('#suggestion').html('Did you mean? <b><i><a href="'+suggestion.full+'">'+suggestion.full+'</a></b></i>?');
```

Comment: yes it works @Ted ! and do you now how to send the suggestion to a input? I add the html code to the first message. I was thinking it will be work with # but it doesn't. I want to send the suggestion to input email.

Comment: @Can ... Sure... use `$('input#email').val(suggestion.full);` if you want the email input to have that value

Comment: great! .. but now it's automatically getting that value.. can we do it with the link?  use the value when we click on the link?

Comment: `$('#suggestion').on('click', 'a', function(e){ $('input#email').val(suggestion.full); });`